# Printing an array as asterisks as if to show that it is hiding another array

Tags: arrays

I am writing a C program in which the user has to guess the name of a randomly generated film from a file of 50 film titles. I need to print out the random film title in asterisks but am struggling to do so. For example if the film is "Django Unchained", then "****** *********" will be displayed.

I have two arrays of 50 characters: Film[50] which holds the title of the randomly generated film and Mask[50] which I intened to hold the masked title of the film. Here is the function I have written to mask the title, yet nothing is printed when I print Mask[50].

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

char FilmArray[50][100];
char Film[50], Mask[50];
int r, i=0;

bool PlayAgain();
void GenerateFilm();
void MaskFilm();

int main()
{
char array[50];

bool answer;

FILE *films;
films = fopen("filmtitles.txt", "r");

if(films == NULL){
    printf("\n ************* ERROR *************\n");
    printf("\n \"filmtitles.txt\" cannot be opened.\n");
    printf("\n         PROGRAM TERMINATED\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

while(fgets(array, sizeof array, films) != NULL){
    strcpy(&FilmArray[i], array);
    i++;
}

printf("\n ************ WELCOME TO MY FILM GENIE GAME ************\n\n");

do{
printf(" Hit ENTER to generate a random film!\n");
getch();

GenerateFilm();

printf("\n %s\n", &Film[50]);

MaskFilm();

printf("\n %s\n", &Mask[50]);

.........
.........

return 0;
}

void GenerateFilm(){
srand(time(NULL));
r = rand() % 49;
strcpy(&Film[50], &FilmArray[r][0]);
}

void MaskFilm(){
for(i=0; i<50; i++){
    if((Film[i] >= 'a' && Film[i] <= 'z') || (Film[i] >= 'A' && Film[i] <= 'Z') || (Film[i] >= '0' && Film[i] <= '9')){
        Mask[i] = '*';
    }
    else if(Film[i] == '.'){
        Mask[i] = '.';
    }
    else{
        Mask[i] = ' ';
    }
}
```

}

**EDIT: Added more of my code**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a typo `Film[i] >= 'A' && Film[i <= 'Z']`. Plus you return a char array but your function definition is **char MaskFilm()**. Apart from these two mistakes your logic is correct. The first mistake is apparent and you can correct it as you have written it correctly for other or condition. As far as second mistake is concerned, you have not passed anything to the function thus I assume your **Mask[]** array is global so in that case make return type void , don't return anything. Select a film name in global array **Film[]** ( as you have done most likely ) in main, call your function and after returning to main print your masked array.
**EDIT**

@KOB I have shared a working version of your code , mainly the mistake was
how you use strcpy. Apart from that there are small changes I have mentioned
in comments of code. Have a look here [Updated Code](http://ideone.com/e.js/4RcVsx). Also I am also
not that familiar with the rules but if you post a code at least make sure
it runs I had to remove somethings and add before it compiled. Do post in comments if you have doubt regarding the code.

Comment: I have corrected the typo and changed the return type of the function to void and done everythign else you said yet Mask[] is still printing out blank. Both Film[] and Mask[] are global arrays and both are created in void functions. Film[] prints out fine and so i can only assume the MaskFilm() function is not executing correctly.

Comment: you are mixing up the concept of pointer and array see how strcpy works,I will edit and post a working version of your code and then you can compare